# CakePHP 3 - additional Controller namespaces

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Is it possible to force CakePHP 3 to read controllers also from other directories, not only default one, e.g. App\Controller\ApiController folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use routing prefixes for having controller in other namespaces, that would be the built-in solution:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

The other solution is to implement your own `ControllerFactoryFilter` and based on any arbitrary rules, find the controller in another namespace. This is the original implementation of the factory:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0/src/Routing/Filter/ControllerFactoryFilter.php

Comment: Thanks, I missed doc's "prefix" part about Controller (used "scope" before). First method worked like a charm. Cheers.